# Where to report API bugs to Google? (Google Nearby Messages API)

Tags: android, api, google-play-services, google-nearby

I really tried to find the best place to post my bug report to Google about the new Google Nearby Messages API but I didn't find anything what would be appropriate for this.

We recently tried the new API and we were very satisfied with it, it works well and our problem isn't a functional bug. Many of our users use the application in hungarian language and the approval dialog for the API is not well designed for us on small screens (Android devices).

This is how the english dialog looks like:
[image]

And this is the hungarian one:

[image]

As you can see, only the Allow button is missing from the dialog, which makes us not to release our updated software with this feature. Where could I post this problem for developers at Google?

I really don't want to post it to a wrong place, for example here: https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at the googlesamples repositories at GitHub.
There is one for android-nearby and iOS-nearby.

https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=✓&query=nearby
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/issues